# How to utilize RightClick function to select multiple cells in table for calculation?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that looks something like this:

[image]

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C25:C35", "I25:I35")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Cancel = True
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G42") = Target.Value

Cancel = True
Target.Interior.Color = vbGreen
   End If
End If
End Sub
```

When I right click any cell in the CLTV Table, it highlights green and auto-populates the value in cell that is highlighted in yellow below. I am able to select multiple cells, all cells are highlighted in green, however, the last cell that is right clicked would auto-populate the value in the Total Purp./Char.LLPAs (#2): field.

[image]

What I am hoping to achieve is being able to right click multiple cells in the table (all cells are highlighted as shown in example) and somehow have it add the cells selected 0.250 + 0.375 + 0.250 + 0.500 and auto-populate the sum into the Total Purp./Char.LLPAs (#2): field.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want the cell in yellow to be equal to the sum of the green cells?

Comment: Correct. Whether one cell is selected or multiple cells, I would like it to auto-populate the sum. And if possible, a reset or deselecting the cell and having the value = 0 or blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - I think this is what you're looking for? Needs a bit more clarification

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim cell As Range

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C25:C35", "I25:I35")) Is Nothing Then

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        Cancel = True
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G42") = 0
        Target.Interior.Color = vbGreen

        For Each cell In Range("C25:C35", "I25:I35")
            If cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G42") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G42") + cell.Value
            End If
        Next cell

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

To reset all colors, assign this to a button or run it separately:

```
Sub ResetColors()

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G42") = 0

With Range("C25:C35", "I25:I35").Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great! How do you go about resetting the value? Thank you!!

Comment: Well I reset it to 0 on line `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G42") = 0` - are you trying to reset all the colors to no fill, you mean?

Comment: Yes, if there's a way click something that could reset all the colors to no fill, that would be perfect.

Comment: Also, for future reference, if I wanted to limit the table to only allow 1 cell selection, how could I write that logic? (example: I click on 0.25, it highlights green, populates, etc. but then I click on 0.50, now that cell is highlighted and populates, but the 0.25 is no longer highlighted or populated) TIA!

Comment: @binmop You'd start the `Worksheet_BeforeRightClick` event by clearing all colors from the area, then just follow your existing logic. But did you still want the cell to be a sum of the previously green cells?

Comment: If I clear all the colors from the area, I would like the Totals cell to be either be blank or 0, if possible. @dwirony

Comment: @binmop Added a line to reset that cell to 0 when you clear it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. @dwirony